# Add contract to interface implementation

Tags: c#, interface, contract

I understand that I cannot add preconditions on an interface implementation. I have to create a contract class where I define contracts on elements that are seen by the interface.

But in the following case, how can add a contract on an internal state of the implementation  that is therefore not known at the interface definition level ?

```
[ContractClass(typeof(IFooContract))]
interface IFoo
{
  void Do(IBar bar);
}

[ContractClassFor(typeof(IFoo))]
sealed class IFooContract : IFoo
{
  void IFoo.Do(IBar bar)
  {
    Contract.Require (bar != null);

    // ERROR: unknown property
    //Contract.Require (MyState != null);
  }
}

class Foo : IFoo
{
  // The internal state that must not be null when Do(bar) is called.
  public object MyState { get; set; }

  void IFoo.Do(IBar bar)
  {
    // ERROR: cannot add precondition
    //Contract.Require (MyState != null);

    <...>
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't - that postcondition isn't appropriate for all implementations of `IFoo`, because it's not declared in `IFoo`. You can only refer to members of the interface (or other interfaces it extends).

You should be able to add it in `Foo` though, because you're adding a *postcondition* (`Ensures`) rather than a *precondition* (`Requires`).

You can't add an implementation-specific precondition because then a caller wouldn't be able to know whether or not they were going to violate the contract:

```
public void DoSomething(IFoo foo)
{
    // Is this valid or not? I have no way of telling.
    foo.Do(bar);
}
```

Basically, contracts aren't allowed to be "unfair" to callers - if the caller violates a precondition, that should always indicate a bug rather than something they couldn't have predicted.

Comment: Can't right now - but the second half of my answer addresses why you can't do it.

Comment: Is this a limitation of contracts or is it a problem of design from my part ? Should I create another interface which includes the property I need to check ?

Comment: It's a flaw in your design. How can a caller use your interface if they can't tell whether or not they're violating your contract?

Comment: @JonSkeet I was going to ask a similar question, but I'd prefer to ask you it in a comment. When you said "You can't add an implementation-specific precondition because [...]", you argue that Code Contracts won't support this use case because it's not possible that different implementations would *require* different pre-conditions. Am I wrong? But at the end of the day, implementations might need specific pre-conditions anyway. For example, an implementation of I interface needs to access a database thus it requires a connection string, but this cannot be reflected by the contract class

Comment: @JonSkeet Wouldn't be this case a good argument to support implementation pre-conditions?

Comment: @JonSkeet In fact, I'm thinking how this would be solved and I believe there's a good solution+design: I interface, implementers and consumers of its implementations won't know that a db-backed implementation would require a database. But I can create another interface which implements I called IWithDbStore (or who knows) which inherits the most abstract contracts and also adds a pre-condition to ensure that any IWithDbStore requires a specific configured connection string....

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer: Well, if a client only knows about the existing interface, you're still adding constraints to that...

Comment: @JonSkeet http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25647220/how-to-ensure-that-implementations-of-an-interface-have-a-connection-string-if-t/25647221#25647221 Check, I've published an auto-answer to explain a possible approach. Would you like to discuss it there? :D