# How to ensure that implementations of an interface have a connection string if they are backed by a database using code contracts

Tags: c#, .net, oop, code-contracts, design-by-contract

Imagine you've an interface like this:

```
public interface IPersonManager
{
     public void AddPerson(string name);
}
```

...and an implementation which we'll going to call `DefaultPersonManager`. Let's say we want to be sure that any implementation of `IPersonManager` won't be able to give a null or empty string as argument of `AddPerson(string name)`. For that matter, we're going to implement a contract class as follows:

```
[ContractClassFor(typeof(IPersonManager))]
public abstract class IPersonManagerContract : IPersonManager
{
   public void AddPerson(string name)
   {
       Contract.Requires(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name), "Person's name cannot be a null or empty string");
   }
}
```

...and we'll decorate our `IPersonManager` interface with the `ContractClassAttribute` attribute:

```
[ContractClass(typeof(IPersonManagerContractClass))]
public interface IPersonManager
{
     public void AddPerson(string name);
}
```

We talked about a `DefaultPersonManager`. It would look like this class:

```
public class DefaultPersonManager
{
    private readonly List<string> _personNames = new List<string>();

    public void AddPerson(string name)
    {   
        // "name" argument will be verified by contract class!
        _personNames.Add(name);
    }
}
```

*Alright!*

Now we need to implement a new `IPersonManager` implementation which differs from the `DefaultPersonManager` in that `AddPerson` should persist person names to a SQL database (i.e. *SQL Server*, it's just an example...). We'll call this implementation `DbBackedPersonManager`.

Since `DbBackedPersonManager` requires a connection string, we could add a pre-condition in the `AddPerson` method implementation of `DbBackedPersonManager`:

```
public void AddPerson(string name)
{
     Contract.Requires(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SomeConnectionStringId"] != null, "A connection string is required in your application/web configuration file");
}
```

**Wrong**: code contracts compiler will say that *`AddPerson` implements an interface member thus we can't add a Requires* (*Read this Q&A [I found that was answered by Jon Skeet and it's someway related to this topic a long time ago.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385485/add-contract-to-interface-implementation)*).

### How would be able to ensure that a specific implementation mandatorily requires a connection string to work nicely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly an approach would be *creating an unrelated interface* called `IWithSqlDbBackend` (or any identifier of your preference...) like this:

```
public interface IWithSqlDbBackend
{
     string ConnectionString { get; }
     string ConnectionStringId { get; set; }
}
```

Later, we'll need to create a contract class like this:

```
[ContractClassFor(typeof(IWithSqlDbBackend))]
public abstract class IWithSqlDbBackendContract : IWithSqlDbBackend
{
    public string ConnectionString
    {
        get 
        {  
            Contract.Requires(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ConnectionStringId), "Connection string id cannot be null or empty");
            Contract.Requires(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[ConnectionStringId] != null, "Connection string must be configured");
            Contract.Ensures(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Contract.Result<string>()), "A connection string cannot be null");

            return null;
        }
    }

    public string ConnectionStringId
    {
        get
        {
            Contract.Ensures(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Contract.Result<string>()), "A connection string identifier cannot be null or empty");

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

...also we'll need to decorate `IWithSqlDbBackend` interface with the so-called `ContractClassAttribute`:

```
[ContractClass(typeof(IWithSqlDbBackendContract))]
public interface IWithSqlDbBackend
{
    ...
}
```

...and implement the interface in `DbBackedPersonManager`. I'll add here the implementation signature:

```
public class DbBackedPersonManager : IPersonManager, IWithSqlDbBackend
```

Finally, if we create an instance of `DbBackedPersonManager`and we try to call `AddPerson` method implementation but no connection string was previously configured in the application/web configuration file (i.e. web.config or app.config...), our pre-conditions will ensure that our application, service or library isn't satisfying the contract to work with persons stored in a database backend!

### Side note

*This is just a sample of how a lot of other domains would be able to ensure a bunch of conditions that, due to code contracts contract classes limitations, would be impossible to verify using regular polymorphism and code contracts.*

Comment: With an unrelated interface, that seems reasonable. At that point you lose a load of the benefits of normal polymorphism, of course...

Comment: @JonSkeet yes, that's it, but since CC compiler cries if you try to use polymorphism, this should do the trick!

Answer (score 1):

Add the connection string requirement to the constructor of your concrete implementation, i.e.

```
public class DbBackedPersonManager : IPersonManager
{
    private readonly string _connectionString;

    public DbBackPersonManager()
    {
        Contract.Requires(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SomeConnectionStringId"] != null, "A connection string is required in your application/web configuration file");

        _connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SomeConnectionStringId"];
    }

    [ContractInvariantMethod]
    private void ObjectInvariant()
    {
        Contract.Invariant(_connectionString != null);
    }

    // Interface implementation snipped...
}
```

Then you are only able to instantiate and subsequently use an instance of `DbBackedPersonManager` if the connection string exists.

Personally I would just take a `string connectionString` parameter and let the instantiator provide the value (they are going to have to read `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings` anyway).

Comment: You're right! This is another possible approach. +1 for the contract invariant.

Comment: It's a valid solution but read the link I posted in my auto-answer where Jon Skeet argues that how a consumer of `IPersonManager` would know about a pre-condition that's not defined by the interface contract? Do you understand the issue? That's why I posted this auto-answer to share with everyone an approach that makes contracts predictable